# Grammar problem

Tags: learning

When that became a hassle , she found a doctor who would prescribe her harder stuff , such as Roxicodone. **It was not difficult, she recalls from her office at the North Wilkesboro addiction-treatment centre she opened in February, after three years of sobriety.**

Can I rewrite the sentence in this way: After three years of sobriety , she recalls from her office at the North Wtilkesboro addiction-treatment centre she opened in February that it was not difficult.' If I am not allowed to do so , can anyone tell me why after  ***it was not difficult*** , there is a clause ' ***she recalls from ....***' despite the use of 'after'.

Comment: Because it was badly written. So it's not a grammar problem. It's not ungrammatical, but it is needlessly complex. The interposed 'she recalls' clause is too long to be a mere parenthesis, and it separates the subject and its predicate. The result is an overcomplicated mess.

Comment: Yep, should be broken into two or three sentences.

Answer (score 2):

A possible rewrite:

> She spoke from her office at the North Wilkesboro Addiction Treatment 
>   Center, which she opened in February after three years of sobriety.
>
> "I found a Doctor who would prescribe harder stuff, such as
>   Roxicodone. It was not difficult," she recalled.

Of course, I am taking great liberties with the quoting, but this serves to illustrate the structure of one way you might be able to rewrite it.

One point I think is important is that the word recall implies a quote, and so the words being recalled ought to be in quotes.

Comment: The "quote" should only be in quotes if it is a direct quote.